# Testing if a function input is an integer

Tags: scripting

I am wondering why code like

```
digitback[n_Integer] := Framed[Reverse[IntegerDigits[n]]]
```

can check if the input for the function is an integer (this is the example given in "An Elementary Introduction to the Wolfram Language"), but when I tried defining my own function

```
DigitCountPi[n_Integer]:=
{Count[IntegerDigits[Floor[\[Pi]*10^(n - 1)]], 0], 
 Count[IntegerDigits[Floor[\[Pi]*10^(n - 1)]], 1], 
 Count[IntegerDigits[Floor[\[Pi]*10^(n - 1)]], 2], 
 Count[IntegerDigits[Floor[\[Pi]*10^(n - 1)]], 3], 
 Count[IntegerDigits[Floor[\[Pi]*10^(n - 1)]], 4], 
 Count[IntegerDigits[Floor[\[Pi]*10^(n - 1)]], 5], 
 Count[IntegerDigits[Floor[\[Pi]*10^(n - 1)]], 6], 
 Count[IntegerDigits[Floor[\[Pi]*10^(n - 1)]], 7], 
 Count[IntegerDigits[Floor[\[Pi]*10^(n - 1)]], 8], 
 Count[IntegerDigits[Floor[\[Pi]*10^(n - 1)]], 9]}
```

no such checks exist, and it will take any n, even if it's not a real number (to which it spits out a list of zeros). 
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Quit the kernel and try again? Try `?DigitCountPi` to check for lingering definitions.

Comment: Btw your code can be simplified to `DigitCountPi[n_Integer] := BinCounts[RealDigits[π, 10, n][[1]], {0, 10}]`